# What's the meaning of "tree"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "tree" in the following sentence?

> Pappus showed how both analysis and synthesis are used to solve
>   problems by working in both directions to find a solution path (a
>   **tree** or sequence of causes leading to the desired effect) that fully links a solution to known causes.

Comment: You are reading a book about a roman era mathematician, but then you don't know about the algorithms and structures of mathematical trees?

Comment: I believe you should ask this question at the Mathematics forum,
"Are there any mathematical significance to the term *tree* in the following passage? ...."

Comment: Have you looked up the word 'tree' in a dictionary? It doesn't only mean the big wooden plants.

Answer (score 3):

A tree here would mean a structure which, if you follow, would give you the complete relation you're looking for- in this case, the link between causes and effects.

The idea of tree here is borrowed from the data structure "Tree" as used in computer science. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure):

> A tree structure or tree diagram is a way of representing the
>   hierarchical nature of a structure in a graphical form. It is named a
>   "tree structure" because the classic representation resembles a tree,
>   even though the chart is generally upside down compared to an actual
>   tree, with the "root" at the top and the "leaves" at the bottom.
>
> A tree structure is conceptual, and appears in several forms. For a
>   discussion of tree structures in specific fields, see Tree (data
>   structure) for computer science: insofar as it relates to graph
>   theory, see tree (graph theory), or also tree (set theory). Other
>   related pages are listed below.

For better understanding, here is a simple tree structure showing the division of an encyclopedia, that might help make things clear (from Wikipedia as well):

[image]